# cordova-plugin-facebook4 get name and email on loginSuccess

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin for FB login:
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4.

This is my simple login method:

```
function login() {
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "email"], fbLoginSuccess, loginError); 
}

var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
  console.log(userData);
}
```

Console logs user data but there is no name and email field there.

Did I set permissions right: `["public_profile", "email"]` ?

Comment: The callback function does get an object containing the login status and authresponse - not user data. If you want user details, you need to make an API request after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the CBroe here is the solution:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api("/me?fields=id,name,email", ["public_profile", "email"], function(response) {
        console.log(response.id + " | " + response.name + " | " + response.email + " | ");
    },
    fbErrorHandler
);
```